# How to get the access_token first in Apex Restful service to call GET/POST methods from outside?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

I am doing Salesforce trailhead from the link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_webservices.

In this tutorial they've use `access_token` to call the `GET` request. **But they have not guided us how to get the** `access_token`, which is an important steps to call the APEX Rest from outside.

[image]

I tied to do something like below its saying me the error:

```
https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id="3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPIzGJ5UZDuKCOqbH8CCGCPnmwQuRbwLZ_2f.thbqWMX82H7JRGx4
6VYyEkuwzQ9._ww5"&client_secret="1180508865211885204"&username="pXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com"&password="AgXXXXXXXX"&grant_type=password
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood the concept now and thanks for sharing other links.

`client_id, client_secret, username, password and grant_type` should be sent in a `HTTP POST` body not in header.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

String CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String USERNAME = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

req.setBody('grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+CLIENT_ID + 
            '&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET + '&username='+USERNAME + '&password='+PASSWORD);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
System.debug('Body ' + response.getBody());
System.debug('Status ' + response.getStatus());
System.debug('Status code ' + response.getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call api to get the access token.

Here's my code in C# to get the access token

async public static Task GetAccessTokenByUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFlowAsync(string username, string password, string token, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
        {

```
        HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient();


        string sfdcConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        string sfdcConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;

        string sfdcUserName = username;
        string sfdcPassword = password;
        string sfdcToken = token;



        string loginPassword = sfdcPassword + sfdcToken;

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type","password"},
                {"client_id",sfdcConsumerKey},
                {"client_secret",sfdcConsumerSecret},
                {"username",sfdcUserName},
                {"password",loginPassword}
            }
             );
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11; //tuanv2t: Salesforce has changed to use TLS 1.1 -> 
        //tuanv2t: Without, responseString will like this {"error":"unknown_error","error_description":"retry your request"}
        HttpResponseMessage message = await authClient.PostAsync("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", content);

        string responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //JObject obj = JObject.Parse(responseString);
        //var oauthToken = (string)obj["access_token"];
        //var serviceUrl = (string)obj["instance_url"];

        var result = new GetAccessTokenResponse();
        result.HttpResponseMessage = message;
        //Convert json string into object
        var accessTokenAPI = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenAPI>(responseString);

        if (accessTokenAPI != null)
        {
            result.AccessToken = new AccessTokenModel();
            result.AccessToken.AccessToken = accessTokenAPI.access_token;
            result.AccessToken.Id = accessTokenAPI.id;
            result.AccessToken.InstanceUrl = accessTokenAPI.instance_url;
            result.AccessToken.IssuedAt = accessTokenAPI.issued_at;
            result.AccessToken.Signature = accessTokenAPI.signature;
            result.AccessToken.TokenType = accessTokenAPI.token_type;
        }
        return result;

    }
```

It's able to download all my source code example here  ( include SOAP API as well )
https://bitbucket.org/tuanv2t/salesforceapidemo

Comment: Thank you so much. This will certainly help.  What if I need to use Postman or rest client ?